# Problem with counting children of process

Tags: c, linux

Ok, let me explain. I have got a programm and tests in a site with courses say, all is OK, but I think I used a crutch.

This program has to count not only lineal descendants, but also descendants of descendants of the parent.

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int count_children(pid_t pid)  //This function work correctly, and count only linear descendants.
{   
    int count = 0;
    FILE* fl;
    char buf [BUFSIZ];
    char path[BUFSIZ];
    int bytes_read;

    sprintf(path,"/proc/%d/task/%d/children", pid, pid);
    if((fl = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fl);
    fclose(fl);

    buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
    int i = 0;  
    while(i < bytes_read)
    {
        if(buf[i] == ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return count;
}

int all_child_counter(pid_t pid)
{
    char path[BUFSIZ];
    int a;
    int count = count_children(pid);
    int counttemp = 0;
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/task/%d/children", pid, pid);
    FILE* fl = fopen(path, "r");

    while((fscanf(fl, "%d", &a)) > 0) 
    {
        if((count_children(a)) == 0)
        {
           continue; 
        }
        else if((counttemp = count_children(a)) > 0)
        {
            //count += count_children(a);
            count += all_child_counter(a); 
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    int count; 
    if((count = all_child_counter(pid)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error! There are no PID!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    count++;     //I must do that to take a right answer.
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

That tests passed, I must add one to variable *count*. I think it's a crutch. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide example, where the code is not working - show the 'pstree' output, or ps -l ?

Comment: For a program with no child, what is expected answer: 0 or 1 ?

Comment: For a programm with no child expexted answer is 0.

Comment: pstree 1304
csd-xsettings───3*[{csd-xsettings}]
 
./childcounter 1304
0

Comment: I'm still confused about what is not working. Consider sample output that shows when the output is wrong. Otherwise, it will be hard to provide you with feedback.

Comment: Shit, I should have read the task more carefully!!! In the task written: "including the process with the specified PID". Now everything is clear! But without you, I wouldn 't have reread the task! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with the assignment. Code looks good, so I'm sure you are on the path to good grade!

Comment: One suggestion - consider using recursion to handle complex process tree - try to see if all_child_counter can work without calling the count_children - calling all_child_counter instead.

Comment: Also, remember to add a check in the fopen in all_child_counter